# Issue with layout when adding 2 pdfreaders on one form

Tags: c#, pdf

I have created a form with PDFREADER on top, then a combobox below it, and below that a PDFREADER. At runtime the placing of the objects become mixed up and the design layout gets ignored. Setting the sizes is of no use. The combobox either lies on the top pdf viewr or vica versa. If anyone could advice on how to force the design time layout not to change at runtime.

1. I add a new form to my project.
2. I add 2 PDF readers from the toolbox to my new form2.
3. I add a combobox to my new form.
4. run the program to see the layout.
5. The layout does not look the same as the design layout. Two lines of Code

   ```
   Form2 fr2 = new FORM2(); 
   fr2.Show()
   ```

Comment: Did you try to put each pdf control inside a panel where you enable AutoScroll?

Comment: Will test and confirm, appreciate

Comment: This worked for me as well as docking the top PDFReader. All's well.Thanks